# Barcode Scanner not working correctly on Galaxy S II

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, barcode

I got my Samsung GS II just recently and I was wondering if the problem I'm experiencing comes from my phone or is a common problem among GS II users.

Once I turn on the Barcode Scanner I'm able to scan QR codes correctly, but when I try to scan a barcode, it rarely works.

If I try to focus the bardcode for a couple of minutes it will work sometimes and scan the code. The camera seems to struggle to scan the barcode, from the looks of it.

Everything else on the phone is working fine so far so I doubt at first that it's an harware problem.

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

EDIT:

Barcode Scanner seems to be able to scan some barcodes if I can scan the code for about 30 seconds or more. This should be done almost instantly when the camera gets a clear vision of the barcode but it seems to take the phone quite some time to lock it down.

Any ideas people?

Comment: What app are you using to scan barcodes, have you tried using a different one? I find Google Goggles picks them up in seconds without any fuss.

Comment: I'm using [Barcode Scanner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&feature=search_result) and I also tested with Google Goggles. It works once the photo of the code is taken. But on my previous smartphone I could easily use Barcode scanner to scan barcodes without any hassle or need of another software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending the whole week searching for this issue and testing different settings and tricks recommended by users from other forums, I have finally found the culprits.

It seems that the least mark of your fingertips on the lens of your phone's camera will make it less sensitive to QR codes and Barcodes in general.
That and also not having AutoFocus *On*.

Things I did that helped:

- Clean the camera lens with a soft cloth to remove fingerprints or other marks
- Turn on AutoFocus On your camera, if it's not On
- Try setting camera Action to Macro, this seemed to make it recognize codes faster.

I hope these tips can help others as it helped me.

Edit:

Also check this [Forum](http://androidforums.com/incredible-support-troubleshooting/69363-barcode-scanning-app-unable-focus-barcode.html) for more tips on this matter.

Comment: @Al Everett, you're welcome. I've edited my post with a link to one of the forums where I found the tips.